# Trouble with accessing object in JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

I can't seem to figure out how to get this code snippet to work. I am trying to access the 'Name' object in this json snippet. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $.getJSON('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=', function(data) {
     $('#demo').text(data[0].Name);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of the actual JSON in the question itself. There may be people who can help you, but can't access the API url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=', function(data) {
        $('#demo').text(data.query.results.quote.Name);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I see that i need to access each object before I grab the one I want

Comment: You're welcome. You might take a look at this for reference: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "query": {
        "count": 1,
        "created": "2017-02-13T18:34:48Z",
        "lang": "es-419",
        "results": {
            "quote": {
              "name": "Blabla"
```

So you have data.query.results.quote.name

Answer (score 0):

Your API call does not return an array, it returns a JSON object.

Try: `$('#demo').text(data.query.results.quote.Name);`

Here's what the data structure that is being returned looks like:

```
{
    "query": {
        "count": 1,
        "created": "2017-02-13T18:34:12Z",
        "lang": "en-us",
        "results": {
            "quote": {
                // other props...
                "Name": "Apple Inc.",
                // other props...
            }
        }
    }
}
```